# reference for wireless routing and mac layer

Tags: routes, tcp, wireless, telecommunication

I wanted to find a good book that explains principles (possibly with some theory) of MAC and routing layers in wireless networks (cellular and wifi). I do not need the bible (classical 800 pages or so books) but, rather, something that focuses on principles, theory, and practical considerations.

Comment: Just wondering, why so high bounty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend 'Routing TCP/IP' by Jeff Doyle & Jennifer DeHaven Carroll. You can search through the book [on google](http://books.google.com/books/about/Routing_TCP_IP.html?id=JjdF2yWqJAwC) and purchase it on Amazon [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578700892).  Note that there is also a kindle edition available.

To cover the cellular topics, I'd recommend 'Wireless Crash Course' by Paul Bedell -- [see here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007145280X).  It's a fair bit cheaper than the other one too.

If you like Bedell's writing style (after spending $30 on the Wireless Crash Course), pick up his Telecom book too.

Answer (score 1):

The [IBM Redbook on TCP/IP](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/gg243376.html) has good wireless coverage. It's a freely downloadable PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest [Computer Networks](http://authors.phptr.com/tanenbaumcn4/) by [Tanenbaum](http://authors.phptr.com/tanenbaumcn4/). It is consider bible (in a good way) on the subject since it has really simple and concise explanations.

It explains each of network layers, including good explanations on MAC and routing in wireless and cellular. Here is books [review](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networks-Andrew-S-Tanenbaum/dp/product-description/0133499456/ref=dp_proddesc_0?ie=UTF8&n=283155&s=books) on the amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't actually said if you will be using the TCP/IP protocol or not I will not recommend books focused on that subject alone. But for most applications the routing of TCP/IP is very good to read about and is almost always covered in most books since it's a the standard way of communication in a lot of places.

But when it comes to wireless specifics I could recommend a bit of different books and papers.

- [An Effort to Understand the Optimal Routing Performance in Wireless Sensor Network](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/AINA.2008.47)
- [Security And Routing in Wireless Networks (Wireless Networks and Mobile Computing)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159454316X)
- [Small online tutorial about routing in GPRS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gprs/gprs_data_routing.htm)

These should be enough to get you going.

Good luck!